# Run npm run start:dev produce ERROR "Cannot find module 'ssh2-streams'"

Tags: docker, npm, ssh2

I am working with docker Nodejs application in Linux Mint 20 OS, and I can run the docker-compose successfully. But when trying to start the application with  `npm run start:dev` it starts watching and then showing the following error:

```
node_modules/node-ssh/lib/typings/index.d.ts:4:41 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ssh2-streams' or its corresponding type declarations.
4 import { Prompt, TransferOptions } from 'ssh2-streams';
                                          
[1:30:24 PM] Found 1 error. Watching for file changes.
```

Plz help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command for missing type package in your project

```
 npm i @types/ssh2-streams -D
```